# date difference between two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, timespan

I want to calculate the date difference between form date and two date..Am using timespan to calculate the difference between two date if date difference is positive means it enter another process falls means it return error message.

My partial code is here..

```
  TimeSpan span = Convert.ToDateTime(txtenddate.Text).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(txtstartdate.Text));
        int formatted = span.Days;
        if (formatted < 1)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid date difference ');</script>", false);
        }
```

In the above code input is end date : 30-01-2004 start date : 01-02-2002

but it returns error message : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

please give me a solution to solve this with out changing date format...

Comment: Try using `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `ParseExact` to get the relevant `DateTime`.

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.ParseExact("30-01-2004", "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                  - DateTime.ParseExact("01-02-2002", "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

While using `Convert.ToDateTime` it invokes `DateTime.Parse` which will try the conversion corresponding to the your current culture setting which as in this case doesn't support the format of `DateTime` you have, so you should rely on the `ParseExact` whereby you know the format in which the string is expected and achieve in fetching your result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the culture for the conversion. By default, it should be using the default date format for your PC but this doesn't always work.

You should take a look at this about specifying a format provider for the Convert.ToDateTime method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t.aspx

and this about the DateTimeFormatInfo object you will need to create to handle the culture: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You must use CultureInfo maybe the default CultureInfo different from "en-GB";

```
var cult = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
TimeSpan span = Convert.ToDateTime("30-01-2004", cult).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime("01-02-2002", cult));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dateformat should be like this.  StartDate=1/2/2002 and EndDate=3/1/2004

Answer (score 0):

> for days difference

```
  public long getDaysBetweenDates(Date d1, Date d2){
return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(d1.getTime() - d2.getTime());
}
```

> Date difference between days with time

```
Date startDate = // Set start date
Date endDate   = // Set end date

long duration  = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
```